# why do ASP menus render in full for a little bit before hiding and is there a way around it besides AJAX script managers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, menu, rendering

My question has two parts.  First and most importantly i want to know WHY for my own understanding of what is going on. secondly what are all the possible alternatives.

For demonstration purposes lets say i have the following ASP page with the following code behind on button1 click:

ASP:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="TEST" Value="TEST"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
onclick="Button1_Click" />

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

code behind:

```
Label1.Text += "<table>";
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        {
            Label1.Text += "<tr><td>random rendered html stuff<td></tr>";
        }
Label1.Text += "</table>";
```

When you click on the button which makes a lot of new html appear on the page, the first thing you will notice (it happens somewhat fast but slow enough to be very much noticeable) is all the menus contents are displayed on the screen vertically including all of the sub menu items.  why is it that this occurs?  is this how menus are always displayed but our eyes dont notice when there isnt a lot of work for the computer to do?  a page i am currently working on has maybe 500 rows in a dynamically created  but also has a lot of css and animations going on. the menu system for that page is also very css oriented and it is very noticeable when the entire menu system covers the page for about a second when the page is loading all the data.

as for work arounds, i already have one work around which i know works which is to add a script manager and make the page ajax enabled.  the loading text displays and when the data returns there are no menu shenanigans.  this is why my post is mainly to understand WHY this is happening.  BUT, i would love to hear if there are any actual alternatives if i have a page that i DONT want to be ajax enabled

thanks!

Leo